# Ошибки в классе Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Прохожу курс по Android, возникли проблемы с выполнение задания.

Нужно сделать простой светофор, по нажатию кнопки - меняется фон.

Вот main.class:

```
package com.example.opimand.oneswitchsemofor;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final RelativeLayout mRealtiveLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    private final TextView mTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button redButoom=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    Button yellowButtom= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    Button greenButtom= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonRed:
                mTextView.setText(R.string.red);
                mRealtiveLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorRed));
                break;
            case R.id.buttonYellow:
                mTextView.setText(R.string.yellow);
                mRealtiveLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorYellow));
                break;
            case R.id.buttonGreen:
                mTextView.setText(R.string.green);
                mRealtiveLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorGreen));
        }
    }
}
```

А вот main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Kitty!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:text="@string/yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:text="@string/red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonYellow" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Куча ошибок в коде, не знаю из-за чего

Большинство ошибок из-за того, что Вы вызываете метод `findViewById(...)` класса активити до выполнения метода `setContentView(...)`.

Например, рассмотрим эту строчку:

```
Button redButoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
```

Здесь Вы объявляете поле класса `redButoom` и сразу же пытаетесь его инициализировать.

Выполнение этой строки происходит при создании экземпляра класса, в этот момент метод `onCreate(...)` активити еще не запустился (соответственно не запустился и метод `setContentView(...)`), в итоге, в методе `findViewById(...)` возникает исключение, так как пока еще не ясно, где именно искать элементы, так как `setContentView(...)` еще не отработал.

Искать какие-то элементы в разметке методом `findViewById(...)` можно только после того, как отработал метод `setContentView(...)`, в противном случае, Вы получите исключение.

Как исправить – смотрите в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606802/220996).

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте инициализацию `view` в методе `onCreate`

```
private RelativeLayout mRealtiveLayout;
private TextView mTextView;

Button redButoom;
Button yellowButtom;
Button greenButtom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRealtiveLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    mTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    redButoom=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    yellowButtom= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRed);
    greenButtom= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGreen);
}
```

А еще у вас в разметке нет корневого `layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello Kitty!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:text="@string/yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonGreen"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:text="@string/red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRed"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonYellow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonYellow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```